# Angular2 http Post Request Error as {"isTrusted":true}

Tags: angular2-forms

I'm getting this Error While im posting Data from An2 to WebApi

**Service.ts**

```
    AddEmp(Url2: string, model): Observable<any> {
let body = JSON.stringify(model);
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this._http.post(this.Url2, body, options)
            .map((response: Response) => <any>response.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

**Component.ts**

```
 Employees: Employee[] = [];
    submit(EmpData): any{
            this._HttpService.AddEmp(this.Url2, EmpData)
                .subscribe(data => {
                    EmpData = data, error => console.log(), () => alert('ok...')
                });    
            }
```

Comment: what error are you getting ? Create a fiddle

Comment: No it Google Browser Error

Comment: Fiddler Response is   Host: localhost:54873
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:51423
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:51423/template/MasterAngular.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

Answer (score 3):

I have got this issue right now.
Reason is event naming.

### Issue:

When you name your @Output as `submit`, you also receive default propagated event.

### Example:

```
// In emitter
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit($event);" > ...

@Output submit = new EventEmitter<any>(); ...
onSubmit(event) {
  this.submit.emit(this.formGroup.value); // Event('submit') triggered
}

// In subscriber:
(submit)="onSave($event)"
onSave(data) {
  // There are 2 events triggered.
  //   - Our manually triggered form data
  //   - Original submit Event with public {isTrusted: true} property.
  this.http.post(uri, data); // So, we call two consequent POST query
}
```

### Solutions:

- Stop original event propagation:

  `onSubmit(event) { event.stopPropagation(); ...`
- rename custom event to something, like `submitData`

Comment: geesh, nice find mate thank you

Comment: @vp_arth believe it or not, I stumbled upon this 5 years later and you managed to free me from hell with this piece of information. I've been stuck with this for about 8 hours searching and searching even more without any clue or success. Thank you so much sir!

Comment: Wow, happy to hear it.